# Rope physics and cutting

Tags: unity, physics, rope-physics

I'm making a game where at some point there is a box hanged from the top that the player needs, and to bring it down he need to cut the rope, but i dont know where to begin how to creat the rope and how to make it cute from the point the player cuts it.
I've did some research and found that i should use joints with links and just cut the link that collides with the knife for example, but i never used joints in unity so i'm still lost and would it look like a real rope if i use joints alone or should i add a line rendrer or something like that?

Comment: This part isn't entirely clear: "would it look like a real rope if I use joints alone or should I add a line renderer" - joints themselves don't render anything, so you'd need some kind of rendering component, either one on each segment, or one dynamically shaped visual spanning the whole chain. What's the alternative to the LineRenderer you're considering?

Comment: what i had in mind when i said that was having like two cylinders and attaching them with a joint that wont look like a rope but more like a chain right? so what i thought is to use a line renderer to cover the space between 2 cylinders that are connected with a joint, again i'm very new to this joints systeme so i might be wrong